# Select All Descendant elements with an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first question so be gentle please. I have searched for hours.

I am trying to create some jquery that will allow me to select the descendant elements of a div class. I want to select every descendant that has an `ID` no matter what that `ID` actually is so I can set some css to it.

```
< ul id="BiggerMenu">

< li id="OptionOnBiggerMenu">Has Content here

< div class="myDiv">

     < h3 id="DoesntMatter" > Menu Header < /h3>
```

< ul>
           < li><  a href=""> Link 1 < /a> < /li>
          < li id="AlsoDoesntMatter"> link 2 < /li>
          < li>< a href=""> Link 3 < /a>< /li>
< /ul>

< /div>< /li>< /ul>

So far my jquery has gotten me this `$(".myDiv h3,li")` which gives me a list of every `li` and `h3` in the whole `#BiggerMenu` and I don't understand why if I specified that I wanted just the `h3` and `li` elements that are descendants of the `.myDiv`.

Even so I tried isolating every element in the `#BiggerMenu` that had an `id` using `has()`, `filter()`, and `attr()`. The closest I got was `$(".myDiv h3,li").attr("id")` which just returned the `#OptionOnBiggerMenu` value.

The ultimate goal is to make the list items that use jquery instead of an `a href` to navigate the site display a pointer on hover. I thought this would work: `$(".myDiv h3,li").filter("id").css("cursor","pointer");`

I am aware I can add a class to each of these elements with `id`'s and use that class to obtain the visual effect I'm looking for but at this point I just really want to know if it is possible to do what I started today - for the sake of learning and getting better at this.

Thank you to anyone who takes time to look at this and respond.

Comment: @Quentin, I wouldn't call this a duplicate because the OP is asking for a jQuery selector, and specifically requests such an answer *(I just really want to know if it is possible to do what I started today - for the sake of learning and getting better at this.)* Your duplicate is pure CSS.

Comment: @Michael_B — While there are a few differences between jQuery selector syntax and W3C selector syntax, none of them affect this.

Comment: I think Quentin is right, its a matter of how I was trying to select the elements and parent descendant, parent descendant was the suggested solution instead of using parent descendant1,descendant2 as I was attempting to do. I just never would have thought to look at CSS solutions when I was stuck in Jquery so thank you all for taking a look at it I will give that a try. (confirmed this worked perfectly)